# How to create Firebase Cloud messaging recurring notifications without console?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

From FCM console I can not set up much more than 10 recurring notifications.

> You can have up to 10 unique recurring notifications active per
> project

I want to aim targeting audiences, user properties, last user engagement also. For example, you can set up a recurring notification that sends a push notification to a user who has been inactive for 2 days. From FCM console it is possible but I want to set it up manually since FCM console does not allow me to create recurring notifications much more than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to create recurring notifications in Firebase Cloud Messaging. Since you already tagged your question with `google-cloud-functions`, you seem to know that you can create scheduled tasks with that.

To create a scheduled, recurring notification you can:

- either [run a function on a PubSub schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) or [enqueue functions with Cloud Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions), and
- combine that with [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens)

From this documentation and the examples in it, you should be able to get the use-case working. If not, post another question with the [minimal, complete code that any of us can run to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).